# How to clear application cache for iphone5 using jquery?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, html5-appcache

I created the web app(iphone 5) for student details using jquery mobile, HTML5 and css. It contains five pages.If i worked in the browser then its working fine, but when i used the web app then newly added record are not displayed in the home screen page .But that records are added successfully in the back end. After went to other page and return to home screen page it displayed the updated details that i have added in the back end. I used the code to refresh the back end for every 5 secs..

I used the methods that all are described in stack overflow.But cache are still there. I used the following methods to clear the cache..

1. Using version in the javascript file like sample.js?v=0.1
2. use ajaxSetup method `({ cache:false; })`.
3. use ajax method
4. use meta tags.